# Is there an equivalent of connectby in PostrgreSQL to go up by tree?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I am learning how to work with trees in postgresql12 and found a good function c`onnectby`.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM connectby('descriptor_value', 'descriptor_value_id', 
    'parent_value_id', '1', 0, '->')
```

Gives the following ouput:

[image]

However, I don't want to build all tree starting from root, I want to get branch to root starting from node (performance). For example, I want to pass as argument `87` and get `1->86->87`. Is there such a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is typically done using a [recursive common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).

```
with recursive cte as (
  select descriptor_value_id, parent_value_id, 1 as level
  from descriptor_value
  where descriptor_value_id = 87
  union all
  select p.descriptor_value_id, p.parent_value_id, c.level + 1
  from descriptor_value p 
    join cte c on c.parent_value_id = p.descriptor_value_id
)
select * 
from cte;
```

---

The `connectby()` function is pretty much obsolete since the introduction of recursive CTEs in Postgres 8.4

Answer (score 3):

I think that you want:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select descriptor_value_id, parent_value_id, 1 lvl 
    from descriptor_value 
    where descriptor_value_id = 87
    union all
    select dv.descriptor_value_id, dv.parent_value_id, lvl + 1
    from descriptor_value dv
    inner join cte c on c.parent_value_id = dv.descriptor_value_id
)
select string_agg(descriptor_value_id::text, '->' order by lvl desc) full_path from cte
```

The recursive query climbs up the tree, starting from a given `descriptor_value_id`. Then, the outer query generates the full path by aggregating the ids found in reverse order as they where found.

This gives you a result with a single row and a single column, that contains the full path to the given node.

You can change the starting node by modifying the `where` clause of the anchor of the recursive query.

---

If you want to use the same logic to get the path to each node at once, still traversing the tree upwards, you can do:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select descriptor_value_id starting_id, descriptor_value_id, parent_value_id, 1 lvl 
    from descriptor_value 
    union all
    select c.starting_id, dv.descriptor_value_id, dv.parent_value_id, lvl + 1
    from descriptor_value dv
    inner join cte c on c.parent_value_id = dv.descriptor_value_id
)
select 
    starting_id, 
    string_agg(descriptor_value_id::text, '->' order by lvl desc) full_path 
from cte
group by starting_id
```

However in that case it might be simpler and more efficient to walk the tree downwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could just swap parameters keyid_fld and parent_keyid_fld:

```
SELECT * FROM connectby('descriptor_value', 'parent_value_id', 'descriptor_value_id', '87', 0, '->')
```

which should get you

```
87
87->86
87->86->1
```